# Can Inno Setup 6 be adapted to check a version.txt file and compare to an equivalent file within an app’s settings folder?

Tags: inno-setup

Can Inno Setup 6 be adapted to check a version.txt file and compare to an equivalent file within an app’s settings folder?

I am not sure whether Inno 6’s in-built version checker reads the data online or downloads a file. Either way, all I need is for Inno to check whether a version.txt file online is the same or different, no need to read and compare a specific value though that would also obviously work.
The version.txt file can be downloaded prior to comparing with a version.txt file within an app’s settings folder.

Comment: To summarize - you want to check online to see if an update is available?  Or you want to compare the installed version to the version of the installer itself?

Comment: Yes to the first question. For macos & linux I download the version.txt and compare to an equivalent file within settings to see if it is the same or different. For windows, depends which method can work with Inno 6. In my scenario it is not the actual program’s version that is checked but a support file found within settings. (Target apps are open source retro apps.)

Comment: Can you use Inno's built in versioning features instead? You can set the installer version to anything you want, it doesn't have to match the actual app. eg https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appversion

Comment: That is what I had hoped to utilise. But I do not know how to adapt the code for the purpose. I am not pascal fluent. Would it be possible for you to provide a sample for me using the the version.txt file within the example?

Comment: I came here looking for help. Both this and my previous posted question went unsolved (previous not even a comment.) I do not pretend to be a pascal coder. Would be nice and highly appreciated if someone was willing to help solve the topic.

Comment: I don't personally know the answer or I would try to help more. Lots of Inno questions get good answers here all the time. This particular question may suffer from being rather broadly written and also doesn't show much evidence of what you have already tried (including what other Q&As you have read here, etc.)  Often people don't like to answer broad questions where they think the person asking hasn't put in enough effort already. (Not saying that is always accurate or fair).

Comment: That’s a fair comment. I am clueless as to how to adjust the code. Not knowing where to start is the reason I did not provide a sample. Only example(s) or references I came across prior to posting referred to registry values. My topic purpose does not involve registry at all, or major/minor versions or licence. The version.txt file is held at sourceforge.net WireShare project. The present value listed within the simple version text file is 1.2.8.5 so the objective would be for Inno Setup to either read the file online or download and compare (as mentioned earlier above.)

Comment: I had been wanting to solve this issue for a couple of years but was concerned about asking too many questions too soon and wearing out my welcome. My previous post-topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74752275/inno-setup-6-2-1-web-download-components-problem shows the url in question.

Comment: Its unfortunately long but lots of good advice in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .  I think if you ask many questions that are within community expectations you will receive a positive welcome. And IMO better to take the chance even if they aren't well received.

Comment: I have read that previously. Other than not providing sample code in this case, which part of the advice did I fail? BTW thank you for responding to me.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/42805224/850848

Comment: Thanks Martin, that code works after all. I recall experimenting with that code a few months ago to no avail, perhaps because I was not sure how it worked. Now I notice HTTP Response: 1.2.8.5 which is exactly what I’m looking for. How might I compare this with an existing version.txt file with an app’s settings folder? Hopefully this is not too basic a question to ask.